# Opening Instagram with Selenium webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to log in to Instagram with selenium webdriber. I wrote a code but It always opens just google chrome page, without going to Instagram page. I have tried to change to `.sleep()` time but It is always the same.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class InstagramBot:

     def __init__(self, username, password):

          self.username = username
          self.password = password
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxx\xxx\chrome.exe")

     def closeBrowser(self):
          self.driver.close()

     def login(self):
          driver = self.driver
          driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
          time.sleep(5)

IGBot = InstagramBot("xxx", "yyy")
IGBot.login()
```

Also I have tried with `\chrome.exe` and with `\chrome`, and with "www.instagram.com".
After 5 seconds, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxx\xxxx\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxx\xxx\chrome.exe")
```

should be

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\complete\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
```

Note not to confuse "chrome.exe" with "chromedriver.exe" in Selenium context.

Comment: I have google chrome but I do not have chromedriver . I do not know how is that possible

Comment: Install it from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). Make sure it is in sync with your Chrome version i.e. if you have Chrome v81, install ChromeDriver v81.